# How to use play() inside Draw() in Processing 3?

Tags: java, audio, logic, processing

I'm programming a game in Processing3 and I have a problem with the sound file. I'm playing `song.play();` on `draw()` and every frame the program is playing again and again, anyone know a way to make it play the background music just once?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what library you're using- is it Minim?

If so, check out [the Minim documentation](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/) for a list of classes and functions that you might find useful.

For example the `AudioPlayer` class has an `isPlaying()` function that you might use to check whether the song is playing before you play it.

You might also want to rearrange your program so that the song is only triggered once, either from the `setup()` function, or using the `frameCount` variable, or in response to user input.

Comment: I'm not using Minim, I'm using library Sound from Processing 3.

Comment: @CHAP Then you could check the Sound library's documentation for similar functions. Or the advice on using `frameCount` is exactly what you're doing with your `x` variable. No point creating another variable. But really, you should just play the sound from `setup()` since that's exactly what that function is for.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a way to make it work. I've created a variable: `int x`; and wrote

```
void draw()
{
   x++;

   If(x == 1)
   song.play();
}
```

This way the song will play only when `x` is 1, and as `x` is growing every frame, it's not gonna be played again.